# How do I send a custom error message to the client a Telerik MVC Grid Ajax Insert/Update/Delete?

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am working with Ajax Editing within a Telerik Grid extension.  I would like to handle errors/exceptions on Insert/Update/Delete and display a user friendly message in the message box that is displayed back to the client, instead of the default message of "Error! The requested URL returned 500 - Internal Server Error" or the like.

Is there a way to tell the grid to display a custom text message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone customized the alert here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/how-to-return-error-information-to-grid-in-ajax-editing-mode.aspx, but I'm still searching for a way to actually update the grid itself...

There's a little hope in the client-side grid's noRecordsTemplate property, but we still need a way to clear the grid of any records that may have already been there.

**Edit:**

Found it: To clear the grid, and set your message, do the following:

```
var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
grid.total = 0;
grid.dataBind(Array());
$('#Grid').find('.t-no-data td').text('My Custom Error Message');
```

Of course, you can figure out on your own how to combine the my example and the example from the link above.

Comment: you can also get the name of the grid using the event argument   var grid = $('#' + e.target.id).data('tGrid');